# Jenkins not reading startup config, problems with https and jenkins

Tags: jenkins, https

I am trying to get Jenkins to use https I have created my JKS file and I have amended the `/etc/default/jenkins` file.  I have set `http_port=-1` and have changed the last line in the file to someting similar to :-

```
JENKINS_ARGS=” — httpPort=-1 — httpsPort=8443 — httpsKeyStore=/path/to/jenkins.jks — httpsKeyStorePassword=chosen_pass — httpsListenAddress=0.0.0.0"
```

Replacing the path to jenkinks with the relevant path and password with correct password.

When I restart jenkins it just defaults to `port 8080` on `http`. It seems to ignore the modifications to this file.

Is anyone able to help??

Comment: I assume you dont actually have spaces between the `--` and the argument

Comment: No I have no spaces between the dashes and the argument.  Do you know why it is not reading the file?