# jenkins not reading config file

Tags: jenkins, devops

I am trying to get Jenkins to use https I have created my JKS file and I have amended the /etc/default/jenkins file. I have set http_port=-1 and have changed the last line in the file to someting similar to :-

JENKINS_ARGS=” — httpPort=-1 — httpsPort=8443 — httpsKeyStore=/path/to/jenkins.jks — httpsKeyStorePassword=chosen_pass — httpsListenAddress=0.0.0.0"

replacing the path to jenkinks with the relevant path and password with correct password.

When I restart jenkins it just defaults to port 8080 on http. It seems to ignore the modifications to this field

Has anyone see this before. Am I editing the correct file??  I am on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins not reading startup config, problems with https and jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001574/jenkins-not-reading-startup-config-problems-with-https-and-jenkins)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001574/jenkins-not-reading-startup-config-problems-with-https-and-jenkins